# Passing additional information around smpp

Tags: smpp

Is there a way to pass additional information around the smpp protocol without using the TLV parameters.

As far as my understanding goes the smpp protocol is complete and no additional information can be passed unless using one of the specified parameters.

Thank you

Comment: you can use semi-useless fields like system_type to store your additional info

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes and compatibility reasons, no. That's literally the reason why the TLVs are there.

If you're willing to, of course, you can define additional parameters, or entirely new PDUs in your SMPP code but for them to even matter, you'd have to control the client and the server side, and wherever it goes on from there to not have those parameters discarded or the PDU treated as invalid. At that point that also is not standard SMPP anymore, it's your own custom protocol that's more or less based on SMPP.